# Find $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{{0}^{+}}}x^x$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

This is what we had discussed in class

$$x^x=e^{x \ln x}$$
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{{0}^{+}}}x^x=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{{0}^{+}}}e^{x \ln x}$$

Now after this my teacher applied L'Hopital's and said the answer should be $1$, but won't that approach be incorrect since $\ln x$ is undefined at $0$ and this is not a $\frac{0}{0}$ form?  $\ln x$  is only zero when $x=1$. Am I in missing something, or is my teacher's method is wrong?

I have tried this myself by another method. As $x\rightarrow{{0}^{+}}$ $\ln x$ becomes more negative and $x$ becomes smaller. So the answer should be $e^0=1$. Is there any way I can formalise this method using a more rigorous approach?

Comment: Think of $x \ln x$ as $\frac{\ln x}{1/x}$ and apply L'Hopital.

Comment: As $x\to 0^+$, $\ln x\to -\infty$ and $x\to 0$. So it is an indeterminate of the form $0\cdot (-\infty)$.